How do I delete a workspace from depot if it has been deleted from my local client?
I had a workspace named him_wsc on my machine which was deleted long back. However I see that the client still exists in the depot.
While trying to delete it using the option
p4 client -d him_wsc

I am getting below error
Client 'him_wsc' has files opened. To delete the client, revert any opened files and delete any pending changes first. An administrator may specify -f to force the delete of another user's client.

Its not possible for me to get administrator access for perforce command, is there any hack or any other way to get it deletd from the depot?

Revert the files.  If the actual workspace no longer exists, use the -k option so that the revert won't try to actually update the workspace files.
p4 -c him_wsc revert -k //...

If you get an error about the client host being incorrect, add the -H global flag (right next to the -c flag) and specify the host that goes with that client.
Once the open files have been reverted you should be able to proceed with deleting the client.
